# CDF: Function of a Random Variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a standard normal Gaussian random variable ~$\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Define a transformation as follows:
$$S(\mathbb{X}) = \mathbb{Y} = \begin{Bmatrix}1, \quad \text{if}\;\; \mathbb{X} \gt 1 \\
\mathbb{X}, \quad \text{if}\;\; |\mathbb{X}| \leq 1 \\
-1, \quad \text{if}\;\; \mathbb{X} \lt -1
\end{Bmatrix}$$

Determine the CDF $F_{\mathbb{Y}}(y)$.

I know for any function $\mathbb{Y} = g(\mathbb{X})$: $$F_{\mathbb{Y}}(y) = P(\mathbb{Y} \leq y) = P(g(\mathbb{X})\leq y) = P(\mathbb{X} \leq g^{-1}(y)) = F_{\mathbb{X}}(g^{-1}(y))$$

**Questions**:

1) $\mathbb{X}$ is  ~$\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ which has a pdf of the form:
$$f_{\mathbb{X}}(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-0.5 x^2}$$
so what is $\mathbb{Y}$ inheriting? When I plug in various values of $x$, I generate the pdf curve  $f_{\mathbb{X}}(x)$.

Basically, what does $\mathbb{Y} = \mathbb{X},\, \text{if}\;\; |\mathbb{X}| \leq 1$ actually mean? Does it mean the random variable $\mathbb{Y}$ takes on the values of $\mathbb{X}$ when $x$ is between $-1 \leq x \leq 1$? The reason I ask is because the pdf itself is always positive.

2) Interpreting, $ \mathbb{Y} = 1, \,\text{if}\;\; \mathbb{X} \gt 1$ and $\mathbb{Y} = -1, \, \text{if}\;\; \mathbb{X} \lt -1$

If I plug in these to the formula for $F_{\mathbb{Y}}(y)$ I would get:
$$F_{\mathbb{Y}}(y) = P(g(\mathbb{X})\leq y) = P(1 \leq y)$$
for example, but what does that say? If $y \geq 1$ is the value of the CDF 1? How can I show this?

**Update based on comments**:
[image: CDF F_Y(y) compared to standard normal]

Comment: I think it is a truncated normal!

Comment: more accurate! I think it is a special case of truncated normal.

Comment: It's certainly NOT a truncated Normal (if one is following the usual terminology). There are two point masses (atoms) at $Y = \pm 1$. Your $S(\mathbb{X})$ is not invertible so you cannot directly "plug in the formula" (strictly speaking there's no $g^{-1}(y)$ in this case). I can post an answer after the old version is deleted and the voting process is done, if you still need it by then.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin My apologies, I have deleted the older post. I simply kept it as the comments were useful such as those by StubbornAtom. However, without keeping my train of thought, they were out of context, which would make the question messy

Comment: sketching the CDF, it would have value of zero for $y<-1$ then take a step function upward to the value 0.159 at $y=-1$, subsequently tracing identically the normal distribution CDF in the interval $-1<y<1$ and then taking another step function leap from 0.841 to 1.000 at $y=1$ and then for $y>1$ would have the value 1.000

Comment: The answer is correctly described in phdmba7of12's comment.

Comment: @phdmba7of12 How do you know the CDF has a value of zero for $y \lt -1$? I understand the CDF is monotonically non-decreasing, but that can't be the only justification

Comment: @Clark, CDF by definition has value of 0 at $-\infty$ and 1 at $+\infty$